# Regular Expression of type x.xxxx for asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am validating textbox text using regular expression. The format is `x.xxxx` and currently I am using `@"\d{1}.\d{1,4}"` but now I want to change the expression to allow `x` and if they press `.` then it should validate for `\d{1,4}`.

Comment: Is x letter x or or place holder of something else?

Comment: Close if you got the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you do it with  `/^\d(\.\d{1,4})?$/`. In C# you do it with `@"^\d(\.\d{1,4})?$"`

Comment: the regular expression should allow 1  1.2 1.23 1.234 but not 1.  23      524

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    // Optional deciaml points
    var regexp = /^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/;
    regexp.test('13.5454')
```

This allows maximum 4 digits after decimal place. But decimal place is optional